# Provide value on 'System.Windows.Baml2006.TypeConverterMarkupExtension' threw an exception

Tags: c#, wpf, exception

I am developing wpf C#, and I got this error while I run my application:
This is my Code

```
    <Window x:Class="Hello.Testing"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:r="clr-namespace:Wpf.Controls;assembly=Wpf.TabControl"
    xmlns:wf="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Forms;assembly=System.Windows.Forms"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    Title="Testing" Height="780" Width="1024" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
    MinWidth="1024" MinHeight="780"
    WindowStyle="None" AllowsTransparency="False"        
    ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip" Icon="Resources/Images/Icons/small_icon.ico" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
```

this is an error that I got:
`"Provide value on 'System.Windows.Baml2006.TypeConverterMarkupExtension' threw an exception"`.

Comment: Are you sure that's all the code? That doesn't seem to be a complete tag, unless you meant to end it with '/>'

Answer (score 1):

You sometimes get this error when you use some image (icon in your case) in xaml but have forgotten to include in your project. You must have copied the image in that directory externally but have not yet included it in your project.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you're using kinda markup extension. 
Does that markup extension is implemented by yourself? 
I remember that the custom MarkupExtension requires you to implement a member method ProvideValue, and seems the exception is on that stack.